Google Chrome doesn't start in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS?
Tried all available solutions online but none worked so far.
Reinstalled chrome several times, through terminal and through the official website.
Tried opening the app by clicking on the icon after installation, the loader spinner showed up for 5 seconds and nothing happened.
Tried opening through terminal. Nothing happens for 5 ish minutes, and then the message Killed appears on terminal, that's it.
I do a lot of web development and would really like access to Google Chrome...any help would be appreciated!
PS: If it helps, You Tube website also won't run on Firefox for some reason, and GitHub's UI doesn't load. It shouldn't be the internet speed causing it cuz I checked that simultaneously.

reboot your computer a MUST i.e. open terminal ctrl+alt+T ; type shutdown -r + ENTER . it will work fine also applies to microsoft-edge browser probably any chromium-based browser.

What makes you think this will solve this user’s problem?

I've faced this problem when installing Chrome/Microsoft Edge. As the other has answered, you actually have to reboot your device after installing those two browsers. This problem only appears on 24.04 because, on other versions, those browsers will work just fine after installation.
Also regarding your question about Firefox, it seems the problem is on your DNS setting. Try resetting your DNS setting or setting it up manually. Source: here.

I rebooted and the problem persist

@JoseCabreraZuniga Try to run it from terminal (just run google-chrome-stable) - it will show what the issue is, for me it was that I changed the computer name(hostname), when I changed it back to the original one, chrome started just fine

I launched the google chrome from terminal to see any error messages, I got the following error:

[11137:11137:1019/221358.031905:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(358)] The profile appears to be in use by another Google Chrome process (9254) on another computer (work-pc).  Chrome has locked the profile so that it doesn't get corrupted.  If you are sure no other processes are using this profile, you can unlock the profile and relaunch Chrome.

This means the Google profile has been locked somehow, so unlock it
cd ~/.config/google-chrome/
rm -f SingletonLock

I relaunched to google-chrome and it works fine now.

Since updating to 24.04 a few weeks ago, I've been swearing about Chrome not starting because of a permissions issue, reading with little comprehension about the new Unprivileged User Namespace restrictions that arrived with 24.04, and not understanding why the /etc/apparmor.d/chrome AppArmor profile wasn't doing what it should.  Then it dawned on me - the Chrome executable isn't called "chrome" but "google-chrome" or "google-chrome-stable".  Did this:
sudo cp /etc/apparmor.d/chrome /etc/apparmor.d/google-chrome
sudo cp /etc/apparmor.d/chrome /etc/apparmor.d/google-chrome-stable

and now Chrome works as expected.
HTH...
